# Use nvflash to install recovery compatible with CM10.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I have a Dell Streak 7 that had some sort of weird "read only" glitch from the factory.  I recently was able to successfully get CM10.1 on it using the files and instructions (nvflash bat file) found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2130081

However, when trying to flash gapps I discovered I cannot enter recovery mode in any way.  I've tried volume up + power, and the orange battery light flashes 4 or 5 times then nothing.  Using ROM Manager Premium and the android power menu to "Reboot to recovery" just boots straight back into CM10.1.  I've also tried reinstalling CWM via ROM Manager and experimented a couple times with nvflash without luck.  Depending on the commands I've tried it just says "NVFlash Started" or "[Resume Mode]" and just sits there forever.

I cannot use fastboot because I can't get the ADB drivers working on my windows 8 machine (I've tried Dell and Google drivers, I have disabled signing, it just doesn't recognize the device correctly).

So what I'd like is a link to an appropriate recovery image (I don't care if it's CWM or TWRP or whatever) and the appropriate command to flash it using nvflash.

Comment: As for the drivers: have you tried [Koush's unversal Windows drivers](http://liliputing.com/2013/04/koushs-universal-adb-driver-for-windows-makes-connectinghacking-android-devices-easier.html)?

Comment: I managed to get the Google drivers working and got gapps installed.  I'd still like to be able to get to recovery mode though.

Comment: Have you ever been able to boot into recovery, i.e. did it just break recently or was it never working? Any error messages when you installed CWM via ROM Manager? Sorry, but I never used nvflash, so I can't help you in regard to that.

Comment: I don't think it ever worked.  As I mentioned, this device is bugged.  It's been sitting with 3.x on it for months, so this is the first time I've tried in a long time... since I painstakingly upgraded it from 2.2

Comment: OK, as I don't know, let's [ask Google for 'nvflash clockworkmod "dell streak"'](https://www.google.com/search?q=nvflash+clockworkmod+%22dell+streak%22&ie=UTF-8) and let it tell us about [1] [Install Clockwork Mod (CWM) via NVflash](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/18525-guide-install-clockwork-mod-cwm-via-nvflash-11-bootloader-only/) and [2] [Restoring the Streak 7 using NVFlash](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=18729637). First two hits, looking promising. I cannot check, but you might give it a try :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that one, but since it's been a few days I'll try again :)

Comment: 404 File not found on the download